# text showing up in hoverinfo not just displayed

Tags: pandas, plotly

So I'm trying to add data labels so you can see the values of each of my stacks when looking at a graph. I added the text option and put the column I want displayed, but it just returns in the hover information and not just displayed on the graph. How do I change this?

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Country': {0: 'Europe',
  1: 'America',
  2: 'Asia',
  3: 'Europe',
  4: 'America',
  5: 'Asia',
  6: 'Europe',
  7: 'America',
  8: 'Asia',
  9: 'Europe',
  10: 'America',
  11: 'Asia'},
 'Year': {0: 2014,
  1: 2014,
  2: 2014,
  3: 2015,
  4: 2015,
  5: 2015,
  6: 2016,
  7: 2016,
  8: 2016,
  9: 2017,
  10: 2017,
  11: 2017},
 'Amount': {0: 1600,
  1: 410,
  2: 150,
  3: 1300,
  4: 300,
  5: 170,
  6: 1000,
  7: 500,
  8: 200,
  9: 900,
  10: 500,
  11: 210}})


fig = go.Figure()

x=[]
for i in df2['Year'].unique():
    x.append(str(i))

for c in df2['Country'].unique():
    df3 = df2[df2['Country'] == c]
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=x, y=df3['Amount'], name=c, text=df3['Amount']))
fig.update_layout(title="Personnel at Work", 
                  barmode='stack',
                  title_x=.5,
                  yaxis={
                     'showgrid':False,
                     'visible':False
                       },
                  xaxis=dict(
                    tick0=0,
                    dtick=1,
                    ),
                  plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)')
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and this block of code helped me!. Im not sure if it can help your case but give it a try.

```
fig.update_traces(texttemplate='%{your_labels =:.1f}', textposition='outside')
```

Go through all the use cases here,

https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/